# extraction of largest connected component

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have binarized an image and found all the connected components in it.Now my aim is to obtain the coordinates of connected component having larger area.i hve used the follwing code
but it is showing errors..

```
           [l,n]=bwconncomp(binext,8);
          for   k1=1:n
               [r,c]=find(l==k1);
               rbar=mean(r(k1));
               cbar=mean(c(k1));
               r1(k1)=max(r(k1));
               c1(k1)=max(c(k1));
               r2(k1)=min(r(k1));
               c2(k1)=min(c(k1));
               len(k1)=r1(k1)-r2(k1);
               wid(k1)=c1(k1)-c2(k1);

          end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show us the errors, although I guess it's due to the out-of-range of your array `c(k1)` and `r(k1)`.

The regions are not necessarily rectangular, so your method to calculate the length and width is only an approximation. Try

```
L = regionprops(binext,'area','PixelIdxList');
```

instead. `L(i).Area` will return you the areas of every region,where `i = 1:length(L);`